# Share the same object between two windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have class representing my `AppSettings`
I have `Main` window and `Settings` window.

Each window contains instance of object `AppSettings`

So these are two objects are different.
If object `AppSettings` in `Settings` window gets changed the changes not reflected in the `AppSettings` of the `Main` window.

IS there any way i can share `AppSettings` object between windows so i have only one instance?

I've tried to create shared base class but got an error

```
Partial declarations of "class name" must not specify different base classes
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the Static Property in one class and create the wrapper property on that static property in other class.

Also if you are binding this property to your UI, then you dont need two propeties.. you can bind to the static instance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is bump to the topic but I found other easier way of doing what is asked so that could help anyone in future.
In every WPF application there is app.xaml and app.xaml.cs created. 
So create a object of setting inside app.xaml.cs and it would look something like this  :

```
namespace WpfApplication
{    
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        // Settings :
        public int setting_1 { get; set; } //some setting variable
        public string setting_2 { get; set; } //some other setting variable
    }
}
```

Now to refer to this object from different window you can use : **`((App)Application.Current).setting_1`**

Answer (score 1):

> IS there any way i can share AppSettings object between windows so i have only one instance?

You'd need some way for both windows to get the same reference.  If you pass a reference to the same `AppSettings` object to both Windows, this should just work.

Comment: i tried to achieve that through base class inherited from `System.Windows.Window` but no way

Comment: @Sreginogemoh That would only work if you were using a single static variable, but it's typically better to pass these into the constructors for the Window, or set on a property, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class like "Utils" on your project with a property like:

```
Public Shared(or Static in C#) AppSettings  As YourObjectType
```

And then in the xaml of the windows make a binding in mode two way with Utils.AppSetings

Comment: They are separate classes

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.  You can make the `AppSettings` property in both windows `DependencyProprerties` and then bind the property in the `Settings` to the `Main` window's property when you create the `Settings` window.  That is, in the SettingsWindow class:

```
partial class SettingsWindow : Window {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppSettingsProperty("AppSettings", typeof(AppSettings), typeof(SettingsWindow), new PropertyMetaData(null));

    public AppSettings AppSettings {
        get { return (AppSettings) GetValue(AppSettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppSettingsProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Then, in the `Main` window class's code behind:

```
partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppSettingsProperty("AppSettings", typeof(AppSettings), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetaData(null));

    public AppSettings AppSettings {
        get { return (AppSettings) GetValue(AppSettingsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppSettingsProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ShowSettingsWindowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
        SettingsWindow settingsWindow = new SettingsWindow();
        Binding appSettingsBinding = new Binding("AppSettings");
        appSettingsBinding.Source = this;
        appSettingsBinding.Path = new PropertyPath( "AppSettings" );
        appSettingsBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding( this, AppSettingsProperty, appSettingsBinding );
        settingsWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

The `Binding` mechanism will keep the properties in both objects in synch.  So if you replace the value of the property in one class with a different instance while the `SettingsWindow` is open, the `SettingsWindows` will be notified of the change and update its copy.